# How did Obito slip through the rubble?

Tags: naruto

In the battle where Kakashi gets his Sharingan from Obito, we last see him being trapped under the rubble where one part of his body is squashed completely,

> but during the flashback sequences shown in the manga chapter with Madara and Obito, we see Madara explaining to Obito he slipped through the rubble.

I thought it was an attribute of his Mangekyo Sharingan which makes him perform the teleportation into Kamui's dimension, which he hadn't activated at that point of time. He is shown to activate that in the later chapters, after the death of Rin.

My question is then How did he slip through the rubble?

Comment: Zetsu is ALWAYS lurking :)

Answer (score 4):

Well my friend to be honest, Mashashi messed up a little at the end of Naruto series, no offense but as a long term Naruto fan I feel that. This is one case he won't be able to fix.

The other case is remember 16 years ago before Naruto was born when Obito tried to capture the nine tails at that point, Kakashi seem to be a little kid  but 4th Hokage fight with a full grown Obito at that point.

Anyway my possible solution to your answer is that someone rescued him and helped him regaining some of his chakra and use Doton jutsu. Unbalance rubber may have been fallen short after Kakashi and the others left.

Comment: seems to me like a plot hole too, i will wait to see what others on this site think

Comment: Good point, but we can take consider that Zetsu MIGHT help him though and yes, Zetsu is ALWAYS lurking.